# Mysql query to display results of all students for a semester

Tags: mysql

I have a semester_student_marks table with the following structure -

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Semester Id</th><th>Student Id</th><th>Subject Id</th><th>Marks</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1234</td><td>1</td><td>55</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1234</td><td>2</td><td>65</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>3456</td><td>1</td><td>75</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>3456</td><td>2</td><td>85</td></tr>
</table>

<br><br>


<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Student Id</th><th>Subject 1</th><th>Subject 2</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1234</td><td>55</td><td>65</td></tr>
<tr><td>3456</td><td>75</td><td>85</td></tr>

</table>
```

I tried the following query -

```
select m.student_id,
       if(m.subject_id=8,m.marks,0) as 'S1',
       if(m.subject_id=9,m.marks,0) as 'S2',
       if(m.subject_id=10,m.marks,0) as 'S3' 
from (select student_id, 
             subject_id, 
             marks 
      from program_exam_marks t 
      where semester_id=1) m;
```

But the result of each student-subject is getting displayed in a separate row as below -

```
+------------+------+------+------+
| student_id | S1   | S2   | S3   |
+------------+------+------+------+
|       1234 |   55 |    0 |    0 |
|       1234 |    0 |   67 |    0 |
|       1234 |    0 |    0 |   74 |
|     654321 |   55 |    0 |    0 |
|     654321 |    0 |   87 |    0 |
|     654321 |    0 |    0 |   60 |
+------------+------+------+------+
```

How do I get my results as -

```
+------------+------+------+------+
| student_id | S1   | S2   | S3   |
+------------+------+------+------+
|     1234   |   55 |   67 |   74 |       
|     654321 |   75 |   87 |   60 |
+------------+------+------+------+
```

My SQL skills are elementary at best so any/all suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things, and you don't even need a subquery here.  Just use conditional aggregation by student, and take the `SUM` of `CASE` expressions to determine the marks.

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subject_id = 8  THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS S1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subject_id = 9  THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS S2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN subject_id = 10 THEN marks ELSE 0 END) AS S3
FROM program_exam_marks
WHERE semester_id = 1
GROUP BY
    student_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim Biegeleisen.

Comment: The answer you accepted is sub optimal and should not be used in production.

Comment: Hello Tim, your solution is indeed more optimal and efficient. I had to generate the sql dynamically as the subject ids would likely vary from semester to semester and could not be hard coded into the sql. The sql query had to be generated at run time and as I am using PHP for development, it was doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation by student, and take the `SUM` of `if expressions` for marks.

```
select m.student_id,
           SUM(if(m.subject_id=8,m.marks,0)) as 'S1',
           SUM(if(m.subject_id=9,m.marks,0)) as 'S2',
           SUM(if(m.subject_id=10,m.marks,0)) as 'S3' 
from (select student_id, 
             subject_id, 
             marks 
      from program_exam_marks t 
      where semester_id=1) m 
GROUP BY m.student_id;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT student_id,
       SUM(S1) AS S1,
       SUM(S2) AS S2,
       SUM(S3) AS S3
FROM
(select m.student_id,
       if(m.subject_id=8,m.marks,0) as 'S1',
       if(m.subject_id=9,m.marks,0) as 'S2',
       if(m.subject_id=10,m.marks,0) as 'S3' 
from (select student_id, 
             subject_id, 
             marks 
      from program_exam_marks t 
      where semester_id=1) m) T GROUP BY student_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, Jay Shankar Gupta. Any reason why the aggregate function sum(s1) was used? This solution works. Thank you once again.

Comment: To add them because only value and all zero is there so you can add them

Comment: If you got your ans you can accept and upvote @VenkatD